# Cannot set shader on object in A-Frame/THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to create a shader, and to test it out I'm trying to assign it to an object on load using the following code

```
AFRAME.registerShader('my-simple-shader', {
    schema: {
        color: {type: 'color', is: 'uniform', default: 'red'}
    },
    raw: false,
    fragmentShader: `
        uniform vec3 color;

        void main(){
            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
        }
    `
});

AFRAME.registerSystem('shader-preview-loader', {
    init: function(){
        this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener("scene-loaded", ()=>{
            let perry = document.querySelector('.perry-the-planeglb');
            perry.setAttribute('material', {shader: 'my-simple-shader'});
        })
    }
})
```

the `scene-loaded` event is custom and works fine, it just makes sure that the scene objects are loaded before doing anything to them.

I'm brand new to Aframe, and the docs tell you to add it to the HTML markup, but I'm using Mozilla Hubs so that's not really an option.

Does anyone know the correct way to assign a new shader material through Javascript

Comment: I recommend sharing full runnable code with glitch.com/~aframe It will be much easier to help you.

Comment: It's literally the Mozilla Hubs source code with hundreds of lines of custom modified code by my company. I'm a 3D artist who's pretty experienced in programming and wants to join the Dev team, I'm just completely lost when it comes to A-frame as everything I do just seems to break, and the docs aren't helping

Comment: @zachThePerson is it a primitive object or a loaded 3D model?

Comment: @zachThePerson I'd recommend never to debug issues like these in a full scale project codebase. Always try to [minimize and isolate the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/fs9vpaog/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing all correctly, except on line:

`perry.setAttribute('material', {shader: 'my-simple-shader'});`

You're passing an object as a parameter, where only string is accepted.

It should be in format:
`perry.setAttribute('material', 'shader: my-simple-shader');`

Also confirm that shader is really registered before init. It should be like that, based on your code, but just for verification.

https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/material.html#register-a-custom-shader-material

Comment: I changed the code like you recommended, but it didn't anything. How would I check if it's registered?

Comment: FYI, passing objects to setAttribute in A-Frame should work. https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-a-component-with-setattribute